# How are win32 executable resources handled?

Tags: c, winapi

I don't know why it's so difficult to find the answer to this question on Google, but I want to set something straight.

Are win32 resources handled in the same way static data is where that data is kept in the RAM for the entire runtime of a process, or are they kept on disk like a regular file until loaded into memory?  Functions like LoadResource / LoadString imply the latter, but I want to be absolutely sure I'm not being fooled by abstraction.

Comment: In general they stay on disk until loaded but...consider it as an implementation detail. For performance reasons OS may decide to fully load an executable in memory (if small enough). Why not?

Comment: It's pretty likely the executable is memory-mapped, so LoadResource just causes that part of the executable to be swapped in page by page and then swapped out as the RAM is needed for something else.  That's how I'd do it, at least.

Comment: @Gene: That is indeed how it is done these days. They are demand-paged in precisely the same way as your code is. The reason for the curious function name is that back in the Win16 days it actually did load the data and the basic API stuck for compatibility reasons. However LoadString does actually "load" the text (it takes a buffer parameter after all)

Comment: "These days" is a bit funny, it has worked that way for the past 25 years :)  Embedded resources are efficient because they don't take space in the paging file.  They are demand-loaded from the executable file, when needed.

Comment: @HansPassant As I recall Windows NT V3(.1?) was vintage mid-90's, and that was the first VM version (a descendent of VAX VMS as I recall).  That would be more like 18 years...  Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In olden days (like Windows 3.1 and earlier), resources were copied into memory during load, and you just got a handle to them.  The memory manager could do things like move the copy around in memory to defragment space or even secretly unload the resource until you needed it again.  When you needed the resource, there was a second step to "lock" it into memory.  This gave you a pointer to the copy and made sure the resource manager didn't move it around until you unlocked it again.

In 32-bit versions of Windows, resources aren't copied.  The executable (or DLL) is mapped into memory, and if you touch the resource, the virtual memory manager will make sure it's there for you.

The APIs (FindResource, LoadResource, LockResource) reflect the old days, with handles to resources, and locking of handles, etc.  But the implementations are much simpler now because the handle is just a pointer to the beginning of the resource and locking is effectively a no-op, casting the handle to a pointer type and returning it.

Answer (score 3):

You may notice that all resource APIs accept an `hModule` argument - this is in fact a pointer to the PE header of the module in memory and not the handle to the file on disk. Thus the resource section of the PE file (`.rsrc`) must be present in the memory space of the program for those APIs to work. Of course, as with all memory-mapped files the data is probably not actually paged into the physical RAM until it's needed.

Comment: With [`GetModuleFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) your strict requirement that the resource section **must** be present in memory for those APIs to work does not hold.

Comment: @IInspectable: that's not a resource API.

Comment: I didn't imply it was. My point is, that module handle and a handle to the file backing can be used interchangeably. I'm not saying that your conclusion is wrong either. The reasoning to reach that conclusion leaves room for improvement, though.